# Segfault when I send structure address

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, structure

I have a structure like this :

```
typedef struct  s_struct
{
    float   x1;
    float   y1;
    float   x2;
    float   y2;
}               t_struct;
```

this is used to draw some stroke on my screen but I have a little problem, I want to change my X value when the right arrow is pressed but it segfaults, I think it's because I don't send properly my structure address...
This is how I do :

```
void            draw_all(t_struct *param)
{
    draw_horizon(param);
    draw_verti(param);
}

void        draw_horizon(t_struct *param)
{

            param->x1 = param->x1 + param->C_Y;
            param->y1 = param->y1 + param->C_X;
            param->x2 = param->x2 + param->C_Y;
            param->y2 = param->y2 + param->C_X;
            param->y2 = param->y2 + param->C_X;
            stroke(param);
}
```

And the function who is called when I press my right arrow :

```
int     event(int keycode, t_struct *param)
{
    if (keycode == 53)
    {
        printf("exit succes.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (keycode == 124)
    {
        printf("====\n");
        printf("PRE C_X = %f\n", param->C_X);
        param->C_X = param->C_X + 1;
        printf("POST C_X = %f\n", param->C_X);
        draw_all(&param);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

My function draw_verti is the same but for verticals stroke...
The segfault is because I have a copy of my structure and I do not succeed to send the address ...
Thank you !

Comment: What is `t_fdf` ?

Comment: Yeah, and plenty more of your code (relevant for this question) is also missing!

Comment: Wrong name sorry...

Comment: `draw_all(&param);` but `param` is already a pointer. Change to `draw_all(param);`

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: You have `param->C_X` and `param->C_Y` but according to the `t_struct` definition you have given, `param` does not have any members named `C_X` or C_Y`

Answer (score 4):

In the `event` function the variable `param` is a pointer. When you do `&param` you get a *pointer to the pointer*, which is of type `t_struct **`. This is not what the `draw_all` function expected.

Your compiler should be complaining about it, ***if*** you had proper prototypes.